# incorrent subnet/mask combination

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, subnet

For a network interface, I have defined a range of addresses for DHCP.

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 08:00:27:5a:3e:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.2.1/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth1
```

and the dhcpd.conf file contains

```
subnet 10.0.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.240 {
  range 10.0.2.2 10.0.2.10;
  allow booting;
  allow bootp;
  class "pxeclients" {
    match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
    next-server 10.0.2.3;
    filename "pxelinux.0";
 }
}
```

However, when I start the dhcpd, i get this error

```
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf line 1: subnet 10.0.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.240: bad subnet number/mask combination.
subnet 10.0.2.1 netmask 255.255.255.240 
                                    ^
Configuration file errors encountered -- exiting
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave an IP address inside the subnet instead of the address of the subnet itself. Replace `subnet 10.0.2.1` with `subnet 10.0.2.0`, and it should work.